# Multiple pattern matching guided string replacements with sed

Tags: sed, while-loop

File1 is an hard formatted pdb file containing protein coordinates:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     -37.809  27.446  34.618  1.00 43.34           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1     -37.480  26.307  33.746  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1     -36.495  25.493  34.556  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      4  CB  MET A   1     -36.919  26.801  32.394  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      5  O   MET A   1     -35.346  25.898  34.661  1.00 43.34           O  
ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1     -36.980  25.729  31.301  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1     -35.977  26.080  29.826  1.00 43.34           S  
ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1     -36.833  27.479  29.055  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      9  N   GLU A   2     -36.991  24.516  35.314  1.00 37.48           N  
ATOM     10  CA  GLU A   2     -36.090  23.617  36.039  1.00 37.48           C  
ATOM     11  C   GLU A   2     -35.250  22.852  35.010  1.00 37.48           C  
ATOM     12  CB  GLU A   2     -36.860  22.659  36.957  1.00 37.48           C  
ATOM     13  O   GLU A   2     -35.776  22.534  33.938  1.00 37.48           O  
ATOM     14  CG  GLU A   2     -37.467  23.407  38.153  1.00 37.48           C 
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
ATOM    981  N   CYS A 123     -15.659  -7.164  13.998  1.00 90.53           N  
ATOM    982  CA  CYS A 123     -16.801  -7.332  13.106  1.00 90.53           C  
ATOM    983  C   CYS A 123     -17.894  -8.234  13.699  1.00 90.53           C  
ATOM    984  CB  CYS A 123     -16.321  -7.886  11.757  1.00 90.53           C  
ATOM    985  O   CYS A 123     -18.918  -8.425  13.046  1.00 90.53           O  
ATOM    986  SG  CYS A 123     -15.266  -6.683  10.904  1.00 90.53           S  
ATOM    987  N   GLY A 124     -17.679  -8.840  14.874  1.00 90.37           N  
ATOM    988  CA  GLY A 124     -18.641  -9.764  15.474  1.00 90.37           C  
ATOM    989  C   GLY A 124     -18.851 -11.029  14.637  1.00 90.37           C  
ATOM    990  O   GLY A 124     -19.970 -11.514  14.513  1.00 90.37           O  
ATOM    991  N   SER A 125     -17.793 -11.536  13.996  1.00 92.09           N  
ATOM    992  CA  SER A 125     -17.837 -12.749  13.159  1.00 92.09           C  
ATOM    993  C   SER A 125     -17.220 -13.976  13.833  1.00 92.09           C  
ATOM    994  CB  SER A 125     -17.117 -12.481  11.840  1.00 92.09           C  
ATOM    995  O   SER A 125     -17.538 -15.108  13.459  1.00 92.09           O  
ATOM    996  OG  SER A 125     -17.831 -11.523  11.084  1.00 92.09           O 
....................... plus many more lines .................................
```

File2 is a list of representative lines obtained from fields 3,4, and 5 of the above
pdb file. To keep all simple, let's consider just to lines:

```
GLU A   2
GLY A 124
```

The desired output is:

```
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     -37.809  27.446  34.618  1.00 43.34           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1     -37.480  26.307  33.746  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1     -36.495  25.493  34.556  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      4  CB  MET A   1     -36.919  26.801  32.394  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      5  O   MET A   1     -35.346  25.898  34.661  1.00 43.34           O  
ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1     -36.980  25.729  31.301  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1     -35.977  26.080  29.826  1.00 43.34           S  
ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1     -36.833  27.479  29.055  1.00 43.34           C  
ATOM      9  N   GLU A   2     -36.991  24.516  35.314  1.00 00.00           N  
ATOM     10  CA  GLU A   2     -36.090  23.617  36.039  1.00 00.00           C  
ATOM     11  C   GLU A   2     -35.250  22.852  35.010  1.00 00.00           C  
ATOM     12  CB  GLU A   2     -36.860  22.659  36.957  1.00 00.00           C  
ATOM     13  O   GLU A   2     -35.776  22.534  33.938  1.00 00.00           O  
ATOM     14  CG  GLU A   2     -37.467  23.407  38.153  1.00 00.00           C 
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
ATOM    981  N   CYS A 123     -15.659  -7.164  13.998  1.00 90.53           N  
ATOM    982  CA  CYS A 123     -16.801  -7.332  13.106  1.00 90.53           C  
ATOM    983  C   CYS A 123     -17.894  -8.234  13.699  1.00 90.53           C  
ATOM    984  CB  CYS A 123     -16.321  -7.886  11.757  1.00 90.53           C  
ATOM    985  O   CYS A 123     -18.918  -8.425  13.046  1.00 90.53           O  
ATOM    986  SG  CYS A 123     -15.266  -6.683  10.904  1.00 90.53           S  
ATOM    987  N   GLY A 124     -17.679  -8.840  14.874  1.00 00.00           N  
ATOM    988  CA  GLY A 124     -18.641  -9.764  15.474  1.00 00.00           C  
ATOM    989  C   GLY A 124     -18.851 -11.029  14.637  1.00 00.00           C  
ATOM    990  O   GLY A 124     -19.970 -11.514  14.513  1.00 00.00           O  
ATOM    991  N   SER A 125     -17.793 -11.536  13.996  1.00 92.09           N  
ATOM    992  CA  SER A 125     -17.837 -12.749  13.159  1.00 92.09           C  
ATOM    993  C   SER A 125     -17.220 -13.976  13.833  1.00 92.09           C  
ATOM    994  CB  SER A 125     -17.117 -12.481  11.840  1.00 92.09           C  
ATOM    995  O   SER A 125     -17.538 -15.108  13.459  1.00 92.09           O  
ATOM    996  OG  SER A 125     -17.831 -11.523  11.084  1.00 92.09           O
```

i.e. a modified pdb with 00.00 in the 11th field if a File1's line contain a
File2 occurrence.

I already know how to do that with Bash while-read and awk but because these tools
change the format and require reformatting and/or specify the output format, in this
particular case dealing with hundreds of files they are not practical.
In order to avoid these problems I decided to look for a solution based on sed.
I got a working solution if I explicitly give a single search pattern. i.e. the
following code works:

```
digits=00.00
sed "/GLU A   2/s/\(.\{61\}\)\(.\{5\}\)/\1$digits/" File1.pdb  > out.pdb
```

but the following does not (the File1 lines are unchanged) and I did not manage
to figure out why:

```
digits=00.00
while read pattern; do 
    sed "/$pattern/s/\(.\{61\}\)\(.\{5\}\)/\1$digits/" File1.pdb > out.pdb ;
done < File2.txt
```

Sorry for the lengthy message. Thanks in advance for any help.

@anubhava:

using my real data this is what happen at the first substitution site:

```
ATOM    293  CE1 HIS A  38     -18.278  19.735  13.486  1.00 67.94           C  
ATOM    294  NE2 HIS A  38     -18.518  18.594  14.144  1.00 67.94           N  
ATOM    295  N   GLY A  39     -13.836  00.00   9.206  1.00 71.50           N  
ATOM    296  CA  GLY A  39     -12.628  00.00   8.447  1.00 71.50           C  
ATOM    297  C   GLY A  39     -11.358  00.00   9.286  1.00 71.50           C  
ATOM    298  O   GLY A  39     -11.411  18.636  10.344  1.00 00.00           O  
ATOM    299  N   PRO A  40     -10.180  17.577   8.797  1.00 71.93           N  
ATOM    300  CA  PRO A  40      -8.908  17.719   9.520  1.00 71.93           C  
ATOM    301  C   PRO A  40      -8.580  19.169   9.912  1.00 71.93           C
```

In this case the site is /GLY A  39/. As you can see there is a shift in some lines and unwanted substitutions in the 8th field.
Strange enough such problems occur only for the first replacement i.e. the remaning output is just perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` in a `while loop` which reads file 2 line by line, you can target only lines matches those found in file2 and carry out the sub on those lines where;

`s/\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\([[:space:]]\+.*$\)/`  - Group everything up to the last digits that matches the pattern and retain to be returned with back reference `\1`. Exclude the number matched in the pattern and once again group everything else after from the space to the end of the line and return with back-reference `\2`

```
$ cat file1
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     -37.809  27.446  34.618  1.00 43.34           N
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1     -37.480  26.307  33.746  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1     -36.495  25.493  34.556  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      4  CB  MET A   1     -36.919  26.801  32.394  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      5  O   MET A   1     -35.346  25.898  34.661  1.00 43.34           O
ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1     -36.980  25.729  31.301  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1     -35.977  26.080  29.826  1.00 43.34           S
ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1     -36.833  27.479  29.055  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      9  N   GLU A   2     -36.991  24.516  35.314  1.00 37.48           N
ATOM     10  CA  GLU A   2     -36.090  23.617  36.039  1.00 37.48           C
ATOM     11  C   GLU A   2     -35.250  22.852  35.010  1.00 37.48           C
ATOM     12  CB  GLU A   2     -36.860  22.659  36.957  1.00 37.48           C
ATOM     13  O   GLU A   2     -35.776  22.534  33.938  1.00 37.48           O
ATOM     14  CG  GLU A   2     -37.467  23.407  38.153  1.00 37.48           C
ATOM    981  N   CYS A 123     -15.659  -7.164  13.998  1.00 90.53           N
ATOM    982  CA  CYS A 123     -16.801  -7.332  13.106  1.00 90.53           C
ATOM    983  C   CYS A 123     -17.894  -8.234  13.699  1.00 90.53           C
ATOM    984  CB  CYS A 123     -16.321  -7.886  11.757  1.00 90.53           C
ATOM    985  O   CYS A 123     -18.918  -8.425  13.046  1.00 90.53           O
ATOM    986  SG  CYS A 123     -15.266  -6.683  10.904  1.00 90.53           S
ATOM    987  N   GLY A 124     -17.679  -8.840  14.874  1.00 90.37           N
ATOM    988  CA  GLY A 124     -18.641  -9.764  15.474  1.00 90.37           C
ATOM    989  C   GLY A 124     -18.851 -11.029  14.637  1.00 90.37           C
ATOM    990  O   GLY A 124     -19.970 -11.514  14.513  1.00 90.37           O
ATOM    991  N   SER A 125     -17.793 -11.536  13.996  1.00 92.09           N
ATOM    992  CA  SER A 125     -17.837 -12.749  13.159  1.00 92.09           C
ATOM    993  C   SER A 125     -17.220 -13.976  13.833  1.00 92.09           C
ATOM    994  CB  SER A 125     -17.117 -12.481  11.840  1.00 92.09           C
ATOM    995  O   SER A 125     -17.538 -15.108  13.459  1.00 92.09           O
ATOM    996  OG  SER A 125     -17.831 -11.523  11.084  1.00 92.09           O
```

```
$ while read -r line; do sed -i.bak "/$line/s/\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\([[:space:]]\+.*$\)/\100.00\2/" file1; done < file2
$ cat file1
ATOM      1  N   MET A   1     -37.809  27.446  34.618  1.00 43.34           N
ATOM      2  CA  MET A   1     -37.480  26.307  33.746  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      3  C   MET A   1     -36.495  25.493  34.556  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      4  CB  MET A   1     -36.919  26.801  32.394  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      5  O   MET A   1     -35.346  25.898  34.661  1.00 43.34           O
ATOM      6  CG  MET A   1     -36.980  25.729  31.301  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      7  SD  MET A   1     -35.977  26.080  29.826  1.00 43.34           S
ATOM      8  CE  MET A   1     -36.833  27.479  29.055  1.00 43.34           C
ATOM      9  N   GLU A   2     -36.991  24.516  35.314  1.00 00.00           N
ATOM     10  CA  GLU A   2     -36.090  23.617  36.039  1.00 00.00           C
ATOM     11  C   GLU A   2     -35.250  22.852  35.010  1.00 00.00           C
ATOM     12  CB  GLU A   2     -36.860  22.659  36.957  1.00 00.00           C
ATOM     13  O   GLU A   2     -35.776  22.534  33.938  1.00 00.00           O
ATOM     14  CG  GLU A   2     -37.467  23.407  38.153  1.00 00.00           C
ATOM    981  N   CYS A 123     -15.659  -7.164  13.998  1.00 90.53           N
ATOM    982  CA  CYS A 123     -16.801  -7.332  13.106  1.00 90.53           C
ATOM    983  C   CYS A 123     -17.894  -8.234  13.699  1.00 90.53           C
ATOM    984  CB  CYS A 123     -16.321  -7.886  11.757  1.00 90.53           C
ATOM    985  O   CYS A 123     -18.918  -8.425  13.046  1.00 90.53           O
ATOM    986  SG  CYS A 123     -15.266  -6.683  10.904  1.00 90.53           S
ATOM    987  N   GLY A 124     -17.679  -8.840  14.874  1.00 00.00           N
ATOM    988  CA  GLY A 124     -18.641  -9.764  15.474  1.00 00.00           C
ATOM    989  C   GLY A 124     -18.851 -11.029  14.637  1.00 00.00           C
ATOM    990  O   GLY A 124     -19.970 -11.514  14.513  1.00 00.00           O
ATOM    991  N   SER A 125     -17.793 -11.536  13.996  1.00 92.09           N
ATOM    992  CA  SER A 125     -17.837 -12.749  13.159  1.00 92.09           C
ATOM    993  C   SER A 125     -17.220 -13.976  13.833  1.00 92.09           C
ATOM    994  CB  SER A 125     -17.117 -12.481  11.840  1.00 92.09           C
ATOM    995  O   SER A 125     -17.538 -15.108  13.459  1.00 92.09           O
ATOM    996  OG  SER A 125     -17.831 -11.523  11.084  1.00 92.09           O
```

Comment: This code does not work, it produces an empty file. Looking at your output I suspect you thought that the dot lines are part of the input while I put them just to indicate a jump of the lines. Sorry for state this explicitly.

Comment: @MaurizioCirilli It works perfectly on my system. The dots are irrelevant and would match what is present in file2

Comment: I rerun your code and yes you are right it works fine. I wonder if you could explain the meaning of the search regex. Thanks.

Comment: @MaurizioCirilli Please check edit

Answer (score 0):

`awk` suites this role better:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2,$3]; next} ($4,$5,$6) in a {$11="00.00"} 1' file2 file1 | column -t

ATOM  1    N   MET  A  1    -37.809  27.446   34.618  1.00  43.34  N
ATOM  2    CA  MET  A  1    -37.480  26.307   33.746  1.00  43.34  C
ATOM  3    C   MET  A  1    -36.495  25.493   34.556  1.00  43.34  C
ATOM  4    CB  MET  A  1    -36.919  26.801   32.394  1.00  43.34  C
ATOM  5    O   MET  A  1    -35.346  25.898   34.661  1.00  43.34  O
ATOM  6    CG  MET  A  1    -36.980  25.729   31.301  1.00  43.34  C
ATOM  7    SD  MET  A  1    -35.977  26.080   29.826  1.00  43.34  S
ATOM  8    CE  MET  A  1    -36.833  27.479   29.055  1.00  43.34  C
ATOM  9    N   GLU  A  2    -36.991  24.516   35.314  1.00  00.00  N
ATOM  10   CA  GLU  A  2    -36.090  23.617   36.039  1.00  00.00  C
ATOM  11   C   GLU  A  2    -35.250  22.852   35.010  1.00  00.00  C
ATOM  12   CB  GLU  A  2    -36.860  22.659   36.957  1.00  00.00  C
ATOM  13   O   GLU  A  2    -35.776  22.534   33.938  1.00  00.00  O
ATOM  14   CG  GLU  A  2    -37.467  23.407   38.153  1.00  00.00  C
ATOM  981  N   CYS  A  123  -15.659  -7.164   13.998  1.00  90.53  N
ATOM  982  CA  CYS  A  123  -16.801  -7.332   13.106  1.00  90.53  C
ATOM  983  C   CYS  A  123  -17.894  -8.234   13.699  1.00  90.53  C
ATOM  984  CB  CYS  A  123  -16.321  -7.886   11.757  1.00  90.53  C
ATOM  985  O   CYS  A  123  -18.918  -8.425   13.046  1.00  90.53  O
ATOM  986  SG  CYS  A  123  -15.266  -6.683   10.904  1.00  90.53  S
ATOM  987  N   GLY  A  124  -17.679  -8.840   14.874  1.00  00.00  N
ATOM  988  CA  GLY  A  124  -18.641  -9.764   15.474  1.00  00.00  C
ATOM  989  C   GLY  A  124  -18.851  -11.029  14.637  1.00  00.00  C
ATOM  990  O   GLY  A  124  -19.970  -11.514  14.513  1.00  00.00  O
ATOM  991  N   SER  A  125  -17.793  -11.536  13.996  1.00  92.09  N
ATOM  992  CA  SER  A  125  -17.837  -12.749  13.159  1.00  92.09  C
ATOM  993  C   SER  A  125  -17.220  -13.976  13.833  1.00  92.09  C
ATOM  994  CB  SER  A  125  -17.117  -12.481  11.840  1.00  92.09  C
ATOM  995  O   SER  A  125  -17.538  -15.108  13.459  1.00  92.09  O
ATOM  996  OG  SER  A  125  -17.831  -11.523  11.084  1.00  92.09  O
```

Used `column -t` for tabular output display only.

Comment: your code work almost perfect. It makes the substitutions at the right lines but when this happen the format is lost, and the lines became space delimited which is the reason why I looked for a solution with sed and not awk.

Comment: To maintain original formatting use: `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2,$3]; next} ($4,$5,$6) in a {sub(/ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ {3}/, " 00.00   ")} 1' file2 file1`

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please see my edit in the main body message.

Comment: I already accepted the HatLess solution but I would consider useful and vote as such your solution if you will provide that.

Comment: The thing you must understand is the difference in approach. sed for this task is totally inflexible and unmaintainable but since you have stated that you're looking for a sed solution only I will have to disengage myself.

Comment: Your solution is brilliant because I did not know how to keep the format unchanged without explicit formatting in a way which is obscure to me. Thanks for your support anyway.